# What is strategic about Chernobyl?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

On the very first day (well, arguably) of the Russian invasion of Ukraine, Russian forces [took control](https://web.archive.org/web/20220224174356/https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/chernobyl-power-plant-captured-by-russian-forces-ukrainian-official-2022-02-24/) of the Chernobyl Nuclear Power Plant and ghost city, as well as Pripyat.

I fail to see how is this so strategic for a first-day goal. Is it only their proximity to Kiev and the border to friendly Belarus? Is there nuclear material that can be reused by Russia? Is there anything else still useful in the cities?

Comment: Please don't use comments to answer the question.

Comment: @convert if it doesn't meet the quality standards for answers then please don't post it as a comment instead. Comments are for asking minor clarifications or suggesting improvements. Comments cannot be downvoted and we don't want lower quality answers in comments instead. If you can backup your assertion (that it's part of the Russian decision-making), then I think it could be an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As early as January, the [NYT was reporting](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/22/world/europe/chernobyl-ukraine-invasion-russia.html) that Ukraine was deploying additional troops to the region due to its strategic location:

> [T]he shortest route from Russia to Ukraine’s capital, Kyiv, is from
> the north. And it passes through the isolated zone around the
> Chernobyl power plant, where the meltdown of a reactor in 1986 caused
> the worst nuclear disaster in history.
>
> In one of the incongruities of
> war, that makes Chernobyl an area that Ukraine thinks it needs to
> defend, forcing its military to deploy security forces into the eerie
> and still radioactive forest, where they carry both weapons and
> equipment to detect radiation exposure.

In addition to sitting in the middle of the shortest route to Kyiv, it also holds a river crossing.

After reports of clashes at the site, this question was put to Dr Jack Watling, a research fellow for land warfare at the Royal United Services Institute on [BBC Radio 4’s PM program](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/m0014pgp) at around 17:39:-

> **Interviewer:** In the last few minutes it’s been reported that the Chernobyl power
> plant, captured by Russian forces, I don’t understand - it’s not a
> working power plant is it? Or, what would be the point of getting the
> Chernobyl power plant - but it does seem something has been going on
> there this afternoon.
>
> **Watling:** I mean it’s fairly standard practice that if you’re taking over a
> country you take over all the critical national infrastructure, and
> Chernobyl has both symbolic relevance but also you can start playing
> dirty tricks in terms of, you know, claiming that, I don’t know, the
> Ukrainians are conducting artillery against it and these kind of
> things. So you know, you want to seize areas that are symbolically
> valuable and areas that are valuable from a services point of view,
> and the Russians will try and do that.

[Radio Free Europe](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-invasion-russian-forces-chernobyl-/31721240.html), meanwhile, cites an unnamed Russian security source, saying that “Russia wants to control the Chernobyl nuclear reactor to signal to NATO not to interfere militarily”. They also quote Deputy Interior Minister Anton Heraschenko acknowledging the devastation that could occur if the site is damaged:

> If as a result of the occupiers' artillery strikes the nuclear waste
> storage facility is destroyed, the radioactive dust may cover the
> territories of Ukraine, Belarus and the EU countries

This suggests that the site may have strategic relevance as a forward base that Ukrainian troops dare not attack with artillery fire.

Answer (score 28):

This one's pretty simple. Look at where Chernobyl is relative to a map of Ukraine:

[image]

It is directly on the shortest possible route from areas friendly to Russia (that is, Belarus) and Kyiv. If you want to capture the Capital and Ukrainian leaders, the fastest route is through the Chernobyl area.

As to concerns about Radioactivity, it's not dangerous on a short or medium term scale anywhere outside of the actual reactor facility and waste storage areas. If the Russian troops set up camp and started farming, or foraging for food in the forests long-term, they might have some health consequences, but there's no concern for military operations.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, does that also mean the Ukrainian defense forces are less active in that area?

Comment: It makes some sense. As I wrote in the question, that seems like the simplest answer, but what about Pripyat? It is far out of the main highway

Comment: @JJJ No idea about that. Reports talked about a heated battle there, so it definitely wasn't abandoned, but I don't know how many troops. Any exposed radioactive dust or debris would have been washed away years ago, but it would accumulate in the soil and forests.  The concern for radiation exposure (outside of going into the sarcophagus etc.) would be eating food grown there (ie plants that took up radioactive istopes, or animals that ate those plants, concentrating the radioactive isotopes). If the troops brought in their rations I wouldn't see any serious issues

Comment: @Rafael I would guess it's about defending their flank. If they moved through there but left Ukranian troops in Pripyat, then they could be attacked from the rear

Answer (score 7):

Today's escalation of the conflict is largely about convincing people of the Russian view: that Ukraine should be controlled by Russia.

Controlling the Chernobyl Nuclear Power Plant is one of the better thought-out parts of that. The idea will be to say that Russia is in control of this dangerous place, which would be a threat to much of Europe if it were damaged. This allows Russia to be portrayed as selflessly assuming responsibility, with the (false) subtext that the Ukrainian government was not being responsible. The only people this is likely to be effective on are the Russian population, and people who outsource their political thinking to Donald Trump, but the latter group are significant in American politics.

It was also an easy place to take and to hold, because the Ukrainians would not be fool enough to fight for it, given the potential consequences of using heavy weapons there. It also means that should the Russians start to do badly in the conflict, they have a threat to employ against Ukraine, which would have to live with the consequences of any breach of the containment.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this. The first point (that people will think Russia is being selfless in taking over Chernobyl) is pretty absurd, and not really something Russia has even claimed (correct me if I'm wrong). And Putin definitely doesn't seem to be all there anymore, but do you really think he'd intentionally use a Dirty Bomb against Europe as a final F-you if they lost? That *would* be a direct, nuclear attack on NATO (among other countries). I buy that it's a secure site that Ukraine would be loathe to attack, but even now I can't see them deliberately destroying it

Comment: @divibisan: There are two sets of people who'll *want* to believe Russia is being selfless in that matter whose opinions matter to Putin: quite a lot of the Russian population, and people who allow Donald Trump to do their political thinking for them. As for the containment breach, how sure can the Ukrainians be that it wouldn't be done?

Comment: I might have misread you. That makes more sense as internal-propaganda for a Russian audience.

Comment: *an easy place to take* - It's been open since 2011 but people ask "Isn't it still radioactive?" It's a good place to get your feet wet w/o a lot of collateral damage; nobody lives there.

Comment: @divibisan : You're right, Russia never claimed that it is being "selflessly" taking control over Ukraine. So far, they didn't even claim that they want to actually control Ukraine, their claim is that they only want to de-fang the Ukrainian military so it can't re-conquer the separatist regions. Whether that remains true or not is yet to be seen, but so far Russia didn't claim they have any intention to control any territory of Ukraine except for those Russian-majority areas which already separated 8 years ago.

Comment: @divibisan, furthermore, Chernobyl has nothing to do with Dirty Bombing. There are no bombs. Meanwhile, we all know, Russia already have nukes, Chernobyl or not. The only way to use Chernobyl as a weapon is to make it explode like in 1986, but this is no good, since it will hurt Russia and Belorussia more than Europe - they are much closer.

Comment: @vsz As of 3-4 days ago, Russia still claimed it had no intention of invading Ukraine at all. Putin has since explicitly stated that he will not allow Ukraine to exist as a self-governing country, and that it should never have been considered a country in the first place. That's not compatible with any future other than full direct Russian control.

Comment: +1 Russia does officially claim that it took the plant in order to avoid a terrorist attack by Ukrainian nationalists.

Comment: @klm123 : it is obvious that if the topic of a "dirty bomb" comes up, the Russians don't have that much need for it, because they have their own nuclear weapons. Therefore it's logical for them to capture the site only to deny it from their enemies. Of course, it wouldn't be logical for Ukraine either to try to detonate it, but one might imagine that if they lose badly (and the odds are in the Russians favor, as they have superior numbers and as of yet no one intervened militarily on Ukraine's side), there might be an act of desperation by radicals to do an act of "if we lose so should you".

Comment: @klm123 The question supposed that Russia might blow up Chernobyl to use it as a weapon or for revenge. If they did that, and I’m very skeptical they would, it would function as a giant dirty bomb  against Ukraine and, depending on the winds, either Russia or Europe.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from its strategic significance, mentioned by others, Chernobyl has **symbolic importance** as a site that is known worldwide and keeps inspiring concerns and investment from abroad. Refusing western collaboration in securing the site or claiming the necessity of such a collaboration can be a useful bargaining pawn in future negotiations.

**Strategic significance** of the site is not surprizing -  power plants are built to be both secure from an outside attack, but also being able to supply with electricity large regions - that is the plant is likely at the geographic point, from which many important population or industrial centers can be easily accessed (at least easily enough for constant surveillance of the high tension line).

Comment: Chernobyl is no longer an active power plant.

Comment: @JohnDallman I never said that it is an active one.

Comment: @JohnDallman what I meant by my last sentence is that the plant is likely at the geographic point, from which many important population or industrial centers can be easily accesses - at least easily enough for constant surveillance of the high tension line.